# Regular expression works with java.util.regex.Pattern but not com.oroinc.text.regex.Perl5Matcher

Tags: java, regex, perl

I came across a bug today in our legacy code which was using the `Perl5Compiler` and `Perl5Matcher` using the following regular expression to validate a UK postcodes:

```
((?i)(([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{1,2})|([A-Z]{1,2}[0-9][A-Z])|([A-Z][0-9]{1,2}))\\s([0-9][A-Z]{2})|(BFPO\\s\\d{1,4})|(GIR\\s0AA))
```

However, it failed to validate correctly for postcodes such as 'G12 4NNT' (the last section is only allowed to be a number followed by 2 letters in this case).  I fixed this by using the `java.util.regex.Pattern` class which correctly uses the above regular expression and passes all of my unit tests.

However, now I'm curious why it didn't work with the `Perl5` ones.  Is there a fundemental difference with regular expression syntax used by the two APIs?

Comment: This might prove helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/a/784452/680925.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is the same than in the [question to the above linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784267/why-do-regular-expressions-in-java-and-perl-act-differently/784452#784452).

If you use in Java the `matches()` method:

```
text.matches("((?i)(([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{1,2})|([A-Z]{1,2}[0-9][A-Z])|([A-Z][0-9]{1,2}))\\s([0-9][A-Z]{2})|(BFPO\\s\\d{1,4})|(GIR\\s0AA))");
```

it matches against the complete string, to have the same behaviour in Perl, you have to anchors around your expression:

```
^((?i)(([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{1,2})|([A-Z]{1,2}[0-9][A-Z])|([A-Z][0-9]{1,2}))\\s([0-9][A-Z]{2})|(BFPO\\s\\d{1,4})|(GIR\\s0AA))$
```

`^` matches the start of the string

`$` matches the end of the string

Comment: Ah, yes, I see now.  Thanks for the detail I was missing!