# Difference between ? and * in regular expressions - match same input?

Tags: regex, perl

I am not able to understand the practical difference between `?` and `*` in regular expressions. I know that `?` means to check if previous character/group is present 0 or 1 times and `*` means to check if the previous character/group is present 0 or more times.

But this code

```
while(<>) {
  chomp($_);
  if(/hello?/) {
    print "metch $_ \n";
  }
  else {
    print "naot metch $_ \n";
  }
}
```

gives the same out put for both `hello?` and `hello*`. The external file that is given to this Perl program  contains

```
hello
helloooo
hell
```

And the output is

```
metch hello 
metch helloooo 
metch hell
```

for both `hello?` and `hello*`. I am not able to understand the exact difference between `?` and `*`

Comment: Don't know about perl, but standard re say ? match any single char, while * match any secvence (0 length or larger)

Comment: Try testing these strings: "xhellx", "xhellox", "xhellooox".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Perl (and [unlike Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784267/why-do-regular-expressions-in-java-and-perl-act-differently?rq=1)), the `m//`-match operator *is not anchored* by default.

As such all of the input it trivially matched by both `/hello?/` and `/hello*/`. That is, these will match *any* string that contains "hell" (as both quantifiers make the "o" optional) anywhere.

Compare with `/^hello?$/` and `/^hello*$/`, respectively. Since these employ anchors the former will not match "helloo" (as at most one "o" is allowed) while the latter will.

---

Under [Regexp Quote-like Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators):

> `m/PATTERN/` *searches [anywhere in] a string* for a pattern match, and in scalar context returns true if it succeeds, false if it fails.

Answer (score 5):

What is confusing you is that, without anchors like `^` and `$` a regex pattern match checks only whether the pattern *appears anywhere* in the target string.

If you add something to the pattern *after* the `hello`, like

```
if (/hello?, Ashwin/) { ... }
```

Then the strings

```
hello, Ashwin
```

and

```
hell, Ashwin
```

will match, but

```
helloooo, Ashwin
```

will not, because there are too many `o` characters between `hell` and the comma `,`.

However, if you use a star `*` instead, like

```
if (/hello*, Ashwin/) { ... }
```

then all three strings will match.

Comment: in fact, it will even match for "helloo" using hello?

Answer (score 1):

`?` Means the last item is optional. `*` Means it is both optional and you can have multiple items.

ie.

- hello? matches hell, hello
- hello* matches hell, hello, helloo, hellooo, ....

But not using either `^` or `$` means these matches can occur anywhere in the string

Comment: The OP says that he understands that, just not the practical difference.

Comment: ie the examples that I demonstrated

Comment: But the confusion is that `hello?` clearly *does* match `helloooo`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example I came up with that makes it quite clear:

What if you wanted to only match up to *tens of people* and your data was like below:

`2 people.` `20 people.` `200 people.` `2000 people.`

Only `?` would be useful in that case, whereas `*` would incorrectly capture larger numbers.