# Boost/Perl Regex Look behind containing OR

Tags: regex, boost, pcre

I'm trying to use look-behind to check the preceding element is a space or the string start:

```
(?<=^|\s)
```

This works fine at `regex101` with the flavor set as `PHP` but gives a syntax error under `boost` (which I believe is `Perl`). I think its the `^` causing the issue. I can't find any documentation as to why this would be so an insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me, please provide some samples and expected results -HTH ;).

Comment: Possibly related question is: [Why do regular expressions in Java and Perl act differently?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/784267/4519059) ;).

Comment: libboost supports several regex flavours, are you sure to select the good one? Whatever, there are small differences between libpcre and libboost perl compatible regex flavour (like this one). As an aside a good workaround can be `(?<!\S)` that handles the two cases. For more complex cases, nothing forbids to write `(?:(?<=sub1)|(?<=sub2)|...)`

Comment: Are you declaring the pattern using a regular string literal? Use double backslashes. If a raw string literal, use single. `"(?<=^|\\s)"` or `R"((?<=^|\s))"`

Comment: Thanks for the help. Seems you just can't use or statements in look behinds directly. Casimir: you're solution is where I ended up so thanks! Just seemed a little long winded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *should* be able to use `|` in lookbehinds in boost, with the restriction that every alternative must have the same (fixed) length.

- `^` is an assertion, therefore has length 0
- `\s` matches exactly one character, so its length is 1.

PCRE loosens this restriction: every alternative must still be fixed length, but they now not necessarily need to be of equal length.

Here's the relevant line in the [PCRE docs](http://pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2compat.html):

> (a) Although lookbehind assertions in PCRE2 must match fixed length strings, each alternative branch of a lookbehind assertion can match a different length of string. Perl requires them all to have the same length.

And indeed, Perl will output the following error if you try:

> ```
> $ perl -e 'm#(?<=^|\s)#'
> Variable length lookbehind not implemented in regex m/(?<=^|\s)/ at -e line 1.
> ```

---

Now, as to the solution, you need to find a workaround. I'll just quote  [Casimit et Hippolyte's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46023778/boost-perl-regex-look-behind-containing-or#comment79007222_46023778) here:

> As an aside a good workaround can be `(?<!\S)` that handles the two cases. For more complex cases, nothing forbids to write `(?:(?<=sub1)|(?<=sub2)|...)`

Comment: Thanks all for the info